# PHP quick start on google apps engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-mirror-api

Has anyone tried hosting the PHP quick start project (https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/quickstart/php) on google apps engine?

The project works just fine for me on my own machine (localhost) but when trying to get it hosted on GAE I'm having all kinds of difficulty. If anyone has gone through this succesfully it would be great to get your insight.

Currently the problem I'm dealing with is the following error upon trying to access oauth2callback.php of the glassware project:

"This webpage has a redirect loop"

Does anyone have any idea of how I might be able to resolve this?

Other problems I've had to deal with:

-Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Google CurlIO client requires the CURL PHP extension'

Resolved by following the advice provided here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-api-php-client/R9zkWsnzUuc

Thank you!

Comment: Curl is not (yet) supported on App Engine. You can give https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client a try instead.